# Correspondent Starters Versions for Spring Boot 2.4.5?

Tags: spring-boot

I downloaded `Spring Boot 2.4.5` intending to get a copy of the libs I need daily. But then I've noticed that I don't have any information about the compatible starters versions to download for it. Can I find those somewhere?

Comment: What do you mean by about download `Spring Boot 2.4.5` ?  Which things you are downloading ?

Comment: Downloading the libs. I intend to use Spring Boot on my Company's computer which is offline. I wish to use the 2.4.5 version for Spring Boot but I don't have a clue for choosing the starters versions of for example Web starter or others. I wondered if there was some sort of list that tells which starter versions a specific Spring Boot version is taking in charge.

Comment: You should consider using Maven or Gradle to manage dependencies ;).  Regarding the versions they should be the same, so 2.4.5.

Comment: I've no other way around so I'll do this like that. If there's no 2.4.5 for some versions, I'll look up to the release date the more closest to Spring Boot 2.4.5 and there you go. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: The starters must match the spring boot version. Also I would really y suggest to get access to internet or at least an internal repository. Trying to download jars yourself, create on offline version is way too much hassle and in the end will bite and hunt you with incompatible versions.